# (WS)Stubs generation - underscore not allowed?

Tags: web-services, jaxb, wsdl, stub

I tried out to generate Stubs from [this WSDL](https://demo.bps-system.de/onyx/onyxexamservices?wsdl) (not my webservice so I cannot change names!)

The problem is that I cant generate stubs successfully because in the wsdl are service names which differ only in that a service with "_" begins and the other not.
Example: _registerTest and registerTest

Someone know how to fix that? Is it possible to generate the Stubs with Jaxb?

I tried with maven:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>ws-source-gen-phase1</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <removeOldOutput>true</removeOldOutput>
                        <extension>true</extension>
                        <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/</schemaDirectory>
                        <args>
                            <arg>-wsdl</arg>
                            <schemaFiles>src/main/resources/onyxexamservices.wsdl</schemaFiles>
                            <!-- <arg>-XautoNameResolution</arg>  -->
                        </args>
                        <generatePackage>com.onyx.player.ws</generatePackage>
                        <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/xjc1</generateDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

And with wsimport:

> wsimport onyxexamservices.wsdl

```
parsing WSDL...

Generating code...

Compiling code...

/Users/blub/Downloads/./de/bps/plugin/webservice/server/OnyxExamService.java:89: error: 
method registerTest(long,String,byte[],Mapwrapper) is already defined in interface 
OnyxExamService
public long registerTest(
            ^
/Users/blub/Downloads/./de/bps/plugin/webservice/server/OnyxExamService.java:114: error:  
method registerStudent(long,long,byte[],Mapwrapper) is already defined in interface    
OnyxExamService
public long registerStudent(
            ^
/Users/blub/Downloads/./de/bps/plugin/webservice/server/OnyxExamService.java:165: error:  
method testControl(long,StudentIdsWrapper,int,Mapwrapper) is already defined in interface 
OnyxExamService
public long testControl(
            ^
/Users/blub/Downloads/./de/bps/plugin/webservice/server/OnyxExamService.java:210: error: 
method deregisterTest(long,String,Mapwrapper) is already defined in interface 
OnyxExamService
public long deregisterTest(
            ^
4 errors
compilation failed, errors should have been reported
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the underscores are removed in order to generate names that respect the [Java code conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) (names like `foo_bar` get generated as `fooBar` in source).

If you want to preserve the name, you can apply some [customizations](https://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/2.2.1/docs/customizations.html).

Assuming I have the files I'm working on in `c:\temp\src` and I'm generating sources in `c:\temp\dest`, I can do (on one line):

```
wsimport 
         -keep 
         -d c:\temp\dest 
         -b c:\temp\src\fix.xml 
c:\temp\src\onyxexamservices.wsdl
```

where `fix.xml` is my customization file:

```
<jaxws:bindings wsdlLocation="C:\temp\src\onyxexamservices.wsdl"
                xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
                xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws">
    <jaxws:bindings node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:portType[@name='OnyxExamService']/wsdl:operation[@name='_registerStudent']">
        <jaxws:method name="_registerStudent" />
    </jaxws:bindings>
    <jaxws:bindings node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:portType[@name='OnyxExamService']/wsdl:operation[@name='_registerTest']">
        <jaxws:method name="_registerTest" />
    </jaxws:bindings>
    <jaxws:bindings node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:portType[@name='OnyxExamService']/wsdl:operation[@name='_testControl']">
        <jaxws:method name="_testControl" />
    </jaxws:bindings>
    <jaxws:bindings node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:portType[@name='OnyxExamService']/wsdl:operation[@name='_deregisterTest']">
        <jaxws:method name="_deregisterTest" />
    </jaxws:bindings>
</jaxws:bindings>
```

Comment: Next problem, I cannot call the Webservice with the generated stubs. Missing something like "createRegisterTest" in ObjectFactory.java? (Im using Spring-WS).

Comment: @user1731299: I'm not familiar with Spring-WS but an ObjectFactory provides methods for instantiating Java interfaces representing XML tags. `registerTest` is a method so you won't find a `createRegisterTest` method in there. Maybe ask a specific question about your new issue so that others can help you more than I can on Spring-WS.